# Find total number of content user created who have greater than 500 pieces of content created, Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is the `.head()` of the data I am using for this calculation:

[image]

Now I have so far done this:

```
group = user_message.groupby('user_id')
agg = group.aggregate({'content_count': np.sum})
agg
```

which gives me this for the output:

[image]

Now I want to just return the `user_id` that have a `content_count` of greater than 500. I thought I could just modify this line: `agg = group.aggregate({'content_count': np.sum > 500})`
 But I get this error when doing so:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: `np.sum` is a function, 500 is an integer. You can't compare these types with `>`. What output do you expect from the `>` operation here?

Comment: Also, you should explain which libraries you are using, and also tag the question with the relevant tags. Numpy, pandas and other python libraries have their own tags here.

Comment: @HåkenLid Will do, editing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
agg[agg.content_count>500]
```